# A standalone software, or plugin to clean up audio.

Tags: windows, audio

I interview people on the street and use a voice recorder to record the conversation. Often street noise makes it very difficult to make out what's being said when I play it back later?

Is there either a plugin ideally for Ableton, Audacity, or Foobar, or a standalone application that will help clean the audio up?

Comment: Audacity already has good noise removal

Comment: @SteveBarnes so it does! You should post that as an asnwer.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the noise removal feature that is in Audacity - find a typical sample of the noise, i.e. a bit with none of the sounds that you would like to keep and use it as a sample for the noise removal feature.

You may need to run the recording through a number of times with different input samples.